# How do you pass down the same function through two components in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a function UpdateHero into a component, then from that component pass it into another component.

When the function reaches the last component it is for some reason no longer a function and this error appears:

UpdateHero is not a function

it works fine in the first component that it is passed into, but I cannot figure out how to pass it into the second one properly.

information.js:

```
import { useHero } from "./hero";
import HeroButtons from './hero-buttons';

export default function HeroesComponent(){
    
    let { hero, UpdateHero } = useHero();
    
    return (
        <div>
            <HeroButtons hero = {hero}  UpdateHero = {UpdateHero}/>
            
        </div>
    )

}
```

hero-buttons.js:

```
import HeroDetails from './hero-detail';


export default function HeroButtons({hero, UpdateHero}) {

    return (
        <div>
            <HeroDetails hero = {hero}  UpdateHero = {UpdateHero}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

hero-detail.js:

```
export default function HeroDetails(hero, UpdateHero) { 

    UpdateHero(something)
}
```

in hero-detail I get the error: UpdateHero is not a function

this is a very cut-down version of the program, the hero appears to work fine when I pass it into hero-detail so I'm thinking its a problem with hero buttons when I'm trying to pass it down

Comment: `HeroDetails(hero, UpdateHero)` should be `HeroDetails({ hero, UpdateHero })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default function HeroDetails(hero, UpdateHero) {...}
```

should be

```
export default function HeroDetails({ hero, UpdateHero }) {...}
```

since `props` is always an object

Answer (score 0):

you should receive UpdateHero function in your HeroDetails as
export default function HeroDetails({hero, UpdateHero}) {
};

Answer (score 0):

you should write below formate in heo-detail.js

export default function HeroDetails({hero, UpdateHero}) {....}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

they way the props have been declared inside the hero-detail.js component is wrong i guess, it should be like

```
export default function HeroDetails({hero,UpdateHero})
```

instead of

```
export default function HeroDetails(hero,UpdateHero)
```

By the way you declared, it should work if you call the function by using

```
hero.updateHero()
```

Because the first argument which gets passed down to that component is for props.